# Wrong stdlib being used for applications compiled with g++49 on FreeBSD 10

Tags: c++, gcc, freebsd

I run FreeBSD 10.1 (which uses the clang stack, i.e. libc++, libcxxrt and friends) and I'm trying to compile an application using *gcc* instead, but having no luck.

I have set my C++ compiler to g++49 and I have verified the stdlibs being linked against are correctly in /usr/local/lib/gcc49, but when the application is run, ld.so searches for libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/local/lib/gcc48 instead:

```
% ldconfig -r | grep libstdc++
        1118:-lstdc++.6 => /usr/local/lib/gcc48/libstdc++.so.6
        1142:-lstdc++.6 => /usr/local/lib/gcc49/libstdc++.so.6
```

causing this to happen:

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc48/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.20 required by /usr/home/ryan/foobar not found

% ldd foobar
foobar:
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/gcc48/libstdc++.so.6 (0x80081d000)
        libm.so.5 => /lib/libm.so.5 (0x800b26000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x800d4e000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x800f5c000)
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to permanently solve this (i.e. not setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH)?

Answer (score 0):

Try, to install

```
 /usr/ports/misc/compat6x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link with `-rpath` to set the runtime library path in the generated executable. This works in a similar way to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without requiring anything special in the environment.